# LyX on Ubuntu produces bad "rasterized" SVG in exported PDF

Tags: lyx, pdf, ubuntu, linux, svg

I recently put some SVG graphs in a LyX document I'm working on.
When exporting to PDF with LyX 2.2.3 on Windows, everything looks as expected (the graphs don't loose quality when zoomed in).

After that I run my file through my system for automated deployment, that exports it with a LyX 2.2.3 installation on Ubuntu by running `lyx --export pdf2 Filename.lyx`.

The resulting file has a "rasterized" version of the SVG image, of which I can clearly see the pixels when zooming in.

I tried installing Inkscape before LyX but not reconfiguring it as suggested, because I didn't find a way to do it through command line. I think installing it before LyX makes the reconfiguration useless anyway.

Is there a way to solve this by only using console commands?

Comment: Welcome! Please always give your version of LyX for LyX questions. If you install inkscape and reconfiguring LyX, does that help?

Comment: I added the LyX versions and information about your tips on Inkscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at LyX's configure script, it appears that the following is the default command for converting SVG to PDF:

```
rsvg-convert -f pdf -o $$o $$i
```

Followed by:

```
inkscape_name + ' --file=$$i --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=$$o'
```

So if LyX finds rsvg-convert in your path, it will use that even if you have inkscape installed. See, e.g. [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9891). Try adding the following to your LyX preferences file (possibly located in the file ~/.lyx*).

```
\converter "svg" "pdf6" "inkscape --file=$$i --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=$$o" ""
```

Alternatively, instead of including graphics the normal way of Insert > Graphics, insert your SVG files using Insert > File > External Material > Vector graphics.